# Induction proof: If $h > -1$, then $1 + nh \leq (1 + h)^n$ for all nonnegative integers $n$.

Tags: proof-verification, induction, proof-explanation

So far I have this:

Prove: $h > -1$, then $1 + nh \leq (1 + h)^n$ for all nonnegative integers $n$.

Base case: $n = 0$

$1 + (0)h \leq (1 + h)^0$

$1 \leq 1$

$1 = 1$

Assume $1 + nh \leq (1 + h)^n$ for all nonnegative integers $n$.

We must show that $1 + (n + 1)h \leq (1 + h)^{n + 1}$

Now I'm stuck. What am I supposed to do now? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Use the binomial theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

As $1+h>0$,

$(1+h)^{n+1}=(1+h)^n(1+h)\ge(1+nh)(1+h)=1+(n+1)h+nh^2$

Comment: Where does the $(1 + nh)(1 + h)$ come from? And how does that go to $1 + (n + 1)h + nh^2$? Sorry for my poor algebra skills.

Comment: 1. Induction assumption: you have assumed that $(1+h)^n\ge 1+nh$

Comment: 2. expand $(1+nh)(1+h)$ and see what you get.